# Variable declaration behavior in if clause Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am bit baffled about the below behavior

```
if true
  foo = "true"
end

if false
  bar = "false"
end

foo # => "true"
bar # => nil
buzz # => 
# ~> -:11:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `buzz' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I expect bar to throw a NameError but it does not, I actually hit this when I was playing around with some friends but nobody could give a clear explanation to this behavior, thanks in anticipation of a clear answer

Comment: That second one @ArupRakshit found is a much better match.

Comment: this is the best answer I have found so far on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415230/why-do-variables-get-defined-when-they-only-occur-in-unexecuted-ruby-code/20415394#answer-20415394 reveals exactly how the interpreter reads the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby, the variables declared inside the `if` block have the exact same scope as the variables which are declared at the top level inside a method. Since the interpreter has gone through the line where it has seen `bar`, its fine with it.

Comment: then why is assigned as nil??

Comment: Because it didn't actually execute the assignment.  Just compiling the assignment is enough for the interpreter to recognize `bar` as a legitimate variable name.  Also, this works with no previous mention of `bar`: `bar = bar # bar is now nil`