# Why do variables get "defined" when they only occur in unexecuted Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

The following ruby statement will result in `x` being "defined" (i.e. `defined(x)` returning `"local-variable"` even if it is undefined prior to execution of this code and even though the assignment is not performed:

x = 1 if false

Specifically, the `x` local variable will be set to `nil`. The behavior is similar for never-executed assignments subject to `while false` and `until false` clauses. You can verify this in either irb or running ruby on some code fragment.

My question is twofold:

1. Is this behavior documented anywhere?
2. Is there a rationale for this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: this concept is called hoisting & the answer is here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928050/why-does-ruby-seem-to-hoist-variable-declarations-from-inside-a-case-statement-e

Comment: @jm0 Thanks. I just voted to close (FWIW, given 100k VTC queue ;-))

Comment: yes sir glad it helped. hoisting is commonly discussed in javascript & i read those docs all day lately :-/

Answer (score 6):

Here's a bit of an insight from the compiler. This is what Ruby 2.0.0 translates `x = 1 if false; puts x; puts y` into (**before any code is executed**):

```
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1] s1)
[ 2] x          
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 jump             7
0004 putobject_OP_INT2FIX_O_1_C_ 
0005 setlocal_OP__WC__0 2
0007 trace            1
0009 putself          
0010 getlocal_OP__WC__0 2
0012 opt_send_simple  <callinfo!mid:puts, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SKIP>
0014 pop              
0015 trace            1
0017 putself          
0018 putself          
0019 opt_send_simple  <callinfo!mid:y, argc:0, FCALL|VCALL|ARGS_SKIP>
0021 opt_send_simple  <callinfo!mid:puts, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SKIP>
0023 leave
```

You can see that the local table allocates its slot `2` to the local variable `x`. The assignment itself (`putobject`, `setlocal 2`) is skipped over by `jump 7`. `puts x` thus fetches the slot `2` and calls `puts`; however, since `y` is not recognised as a local variable either in this scope or a higher one, it is thought it might be a method, really, almost as if you had written `puts(y())`. At execution time, `y` cannot be resolved, and the error is raised.

Comment: I asked a similar question, this seems to be the best explanation ever, @Amadan, how did you get this to display??

Comment: @bjhaid: `puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile('x = 1 if false; puts x; puts y').disasm`